# Python loop from begining without running again the code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know how I'm supposed to loop this code from the beginning without running the code again. I know I should put while True():

```
list_of_students = ["Michele", "Sara", "Cassie", "Andrew"]
name = input("Type name to check: ")
if name in list_of_students:
    print("This student is enrolled.")
elif name not in list_of_students:
    print("This student is not enrolled.")
```

while True:

If I don't want to duplicate the code, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to create a program that infinitely accepts a search argument?

If so the code would look like so:

```
list_of_students = ["Michele", "Sara", "Cassie", "Andrew"]

while True:
    name = input("Type name to check: ")
    if name in list_of_students:
        print("This student is enrolled.")
    else:
        print("This student is not enrolled.")
```

Otherwise please further explain the problem.

Comment: yes, that was my problem. I didn't know where to put the while true. Thanks

Comment: Ok good. I'm glad I could be of assistance. Although, it would likely be useful to understand the code fully. What about it confused you?

And thanks @CoryMadden for the edit. Didn't even notice it.

Comment: No problem. Was just going to change the `True()` part, but edits have to be 6 characters or more.

Answer (score 1):

While True should be sufficient to have that input test run repeatedly.

```
while True:
        name = input("Enter a name to check: ")
        if name in list_of_students:
            print("This student is enrolled")
        else:
            print("This student is not enrolled")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_students = ["Michele", "Sara", "Cassie", "Andrew"]

def student_checker(name): 
    if name == list_of_students:
        print("This student is enrolled.")
    elif name not in list_of_students:
        print("This student is not enrolled.")


# Test to make sure it is working, comment out when not wanted
student_checker("Michele")
student_checker("Anthony")


while True:
    name = input("Type name to check: ")
```

NOTE: this will run continuously, please make sure to add a breaking condition when you want the code to finish.